# FFMPEG convert video file from FLV to MP4 not running on browser

Tags: php, video, ffmpeg

I am using FFMPEG for converting video file from FLV, AVI to mp4.
FFMPEG is converting file properly on server. I have played that video, it's playing fine but it's not running on browser while after converting file from local machine, it's playing fine on browser also.

Local Machine : Ubuntu 12.04

Server Machine : Centos

Comment: How can we know what the issue is without seeing your `ffmpeg` command and the complete console/log output?

Comment: On console,  command is not giving any error. Its successfully converted and also playing on VLC player but not playing on browser. In Chrome browser, only play audio and firefox giving me message file is corrupted. This issue is coming on only server not a local machine. I have tested our code on Ubuntu 12.04 and 14.04. Please help me.

Answer (score 1):

I have found solution for this issue.

Due to some package dependencies this issue is coming.

We can use below command :

```
ffmpeg -i $video_from -acodec libfaac -ab 96k -vcodec libx264 -vpre slower -vpre main -level 21 -refs 2 -b 345k -bt 345k -threads 0 -s 640x360 $video_to
```

Now its working fine :)

Comment: You must be using a really old `ffmpeg` if you're using `-vpre`.

Comment: Yes, its FFMPEG 0.6 version

Comment: That is ancient and unsupported. Please use a build from a recent epoch.